# CSS issue with multiple items floated left and one item floated right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having an issue with floats in the header of this web page - http://test.debtfree.co.uk/. My markup is as follows:

```
<div class = "landline">
 <!--content-->
</div>
<div class="mobile">
 <!--content-->
</div>
<div class="times">
 <!--content-->              
</div>
<a class="callback">
 <!--content-->                        
</a>
```

I have applied a `float:left` rule to `.landline`, `.mobile` and `.times`
I have also appled a `float:right` to `.callback`.

The issue is that when I resize the browser horizontally slightly from the left `.callback` (contains the text - "Request We Call You")  will wrap underneath the other elements, whereas I would rather that it sits inline with the elements that are floated left.

However I have found that if I move `.callback` to the top of the HTML fragment, so that it is at the top of the browser reading order then the issue is removed. However, I am fairly certain postioning my elements using the browser reading order is bad pratice. By stating the `.callback` first (and floating it right) I tell the element to float right first, but surely there is a better way to achieve this with CSS?

```
<a class="callback">
 <!--content-->                        
</a>
<div class = "landline">
 <!--content-->
</div>
<div class="mobile">
 <!--content-->
</div>
<div class="times">
 <!--content-->              
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-area .landline,.top-area .mobile {
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
}

.top-area .times {
color:#6289d8;
float:left;
}

.top-area .callback {
border:1px solid #888;
color:#36C;
display:block;
float:right;
font-weight:700;
text-align:right;
box-shadow:1px 1px 4px 2px #DDD;
padding:7px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You can achieve the desired result by placing `.callback` at the top, but you'd rather place it at the bottom?

Comment: Yes I have placed .callback at the top to acheive a postioning fix, but following a logical HTML reading order .callback should appear at the bottom and then be styled with CSS.

Comment: @user3749125 If you link your site, please don't protect it with a password. A fiddle would be better, though.

Comment: @Oriol sorry about that, password protection is off.

Comment: If you want `.callback` at the end, I think the only way is absolute positioning, or maybe CSS3 FlexBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

you can:
remove `float:right` from `.callback` and add:

```
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: 0;
width: 140px;
```

It looks good until screen widths greater than 1340px, then you could just adjust with media queries.